# How to search for a string to mysql db column?

Tags: php, sql

I've a Mysql db table column which name is `notesUpdate`. In this column data are contain like this:

```
$string = "{ASUSIBBIR}09-27-2014 19:38 PM alex : hmm..{ASUSIBBIR}{ASUSIBBIR}09-27-2014 20:04  
PM alex : note here..{ASUSIBBIR}{ASUSIBBIR}
```

Now I want to search in this column using `sql` query. I'm using following `query`to search..

```
$getSearch = "my join query............";
if($ad_noteterm){    
    $getSearch .= "AND LOCATE('$ad_noteterm', cd.notesUpdate)"; 
}
```

Using this `query` I can get result but problem is I want to search without following Text..

```
{ASUSIBBIR}09-27-2014 19:38 PM alex :
```

So Search result should be **hmm..** or **note here** if i search on it. I've no idea **what is the Sql query should be ?**

Without db table column I can search to string using following `regular expression`..

```
$match[0] = '/\{ASUSIBBIR\}(.+?)\s:\s/';
$match[1] = '/\{ASUSIBBIRsss\}/';
$haystack = preg_replace($match, '', $string);
```

**BUT HOW CAN I USE THIS IN SQL QUERY TO GET THE RESULT ?**

Thank You!!

Comment: Consider changing your database design and storing different things in different columns instead of creating one big blob of text that you have to search through and split later.

Comment: @Fabian your idea is good. But Is there any way to search in this situation ?